# Using a different test/train split for each target

Tags: scikit-learn

I plan on using a data set which contains 3 target values of interest. Ultimately I will be trying classification methods on a binary target and also plan on using regression methods for two separate continuous targets.

Is is it a bad practice to do a different train/test split for each target variable?

Otherwise, I am not sure how to split the data in a way that will allow me to predict each target, separately.

Answer (score 0):

If they're effectively 3 different models trained and evaluated separately then for the purposes of scientifically evaluating each model's performance it doesn't matter if you use different test-train splits for each model, as no information will be leaking from model to model. But if you plan on comparing the results of the 3 models or combining all 3 scores into some aggregate metric then you would want to use the same test-train split so that all 3 models are working from the same training data, as otherwise the performance of each model will likely depend to some extent on the test data for the other models, and therefore your combined score will to some extent be a function of your test data.